# How to create this kind of matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

Given number from 1 to 12, is there any existing function that can create the following matrix with option to specify something like `size` here? I can only think of creating each matrix using by.column and bind them together using `rbind`. Is there any cleaner option for this?

```
m <- matrix(1:12, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
```

Desired output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    7    9   11
[4,]    8   10   12
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is cleaner (given the matrix not the vector as you don't specify the number of columns):

```
m <- matrix(1:12, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

size <- 2
cols <- ncol(m)
m2 <- c(apply(m, 1, c))

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(m2, rep(seq_len(length(m2) /(size*cols)), each = size*cols)), matrix, nrow = size))

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    3    5
## [2,]    2    4    6
## [3,]    7    9   11
## [4,]    8   10   12
```

Comment: Tested the code and it works perfectly. Thank you so much! I will try to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think `aperm()` would be useful here

```
mymat<-function(size, ncol=3, start=1, end=12) {
    v <- start:end
    stopifnot(length(v)%%ncol==0, length(v)%%size==0)

    a <- array(v, dim=c(length(v)/ncol/size, ncol, size))
    matrix(aperm(a, c(1,3,2)), ncol=ncol)
}

mymat(2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    4    6
# [3,]    7    9   11
# [4,]    8   10   12
```